# Writing to two cassandra tables with time overlap

Tags: cassandra

I am writing to two cassandra tables, the tables have different keyspaces. I am wondering about how the write actually happens.

I see this explanation at: https://academy.datastax.com/demos/brief-introduction-apache-cassandra

> Cassandra is well known for its impressive performance in both reading
>   and writing data. Data is written to Cassandra in a way that provides
>   both full data durability and high performance. Data written to a
>   Cassandra node is first recorded in an on-disk commit log and then
>   written to a memory-based structure called a memtable. When a
>   memtable’s size exceeds a configurable threshold, the data is written
>   to an immutable file on disk called an SSTable. Buffering writes in
>   memory in this way allows writes always to be a fully sequential
>   operation, with many megabytes of disk I/O happening at the same time,
>   rather than one at a time over a long period. This architecture gives
>   Cassandra its legendary write performance

But this does not explain what happens if I write to two tables in overlapping time period.

Let's say I am writing to `Table 1` and `Table 2` at the same time. The entries that I want to write would still be stored in the same `memtable`, correct? They would essentially be mixed, right?

Let's say I am writing 100,000,000 entries for `Table 1` and 10 minutes later I started to write entries 100 for `Table 2`. The 100 for `Table 2` would still have to wait for entries for `Table 1` to be processed, since they are sharing the same `memtable` right?

Is my understanding about how `memtable` is shared correct? Is there a way for different keyspaces to have their own `memtable`. For example, if I really want to make sure that entries for `Table 2` get written without a delay, is that possible?

.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Memtables and SSTables are maintained per table. So when table2 writes it will be written to a corresponding memtable for table2. Data from table1 will be written to corresponding memtable for table1. Every once in a while the memtable is flushed on disk in a SSTable

Comment: @Zerd1984, I think you understood my question. If memtables are maintained per table then my understanding of memtables was wrong, which is what I was asking. Thank You. Do you know of any resources that explain this issue in more detail?

Comment: The Datastax Academy is a great resource. For architectural informations I recommend this video-series: https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds201-cassandra-core-concepts This is free, however you have to register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each table have its own memtable. Cassandra does not mix things. That is why it can easily and efficiently flush data on the disk when memtables total space is full.

This [Datastax document](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_write_path_c.html#concept_ds_wt3_32w_zj__dml-flushing) is a good summary of how writing in Cassandra is performed from commitlog to sstable and compaction.